# Extra condition for existing XML parsing code

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

The main Focuse on the `SequenceNum` column / field. In this field present code counts and numbers the chains of sequences between full coincidenced  X and Y coordinates. For example in the node within `Parcel` ID = 1 there are equal coordinates with `PointNum` 1 and 4, 5 and 7. So each sequence between equal coordinates are getting the same number in the `SequenceNum` field, like 1-1-1-1,  2-2-2, 3-3-3-3 etc..
(And as a common rule: the first PointNum is always equal the last PointNum inside each Parcel element).

The goal of this **question is** to explicate situation when there are no inner sequences of full coincidence of coordinates. No additional chains between first PointNum=1 and the last one PointNum=1.
While technicaly this situation in field `SequenceNum` explicates like 1-then-null-null-null (for all PointNums). I need to extend present code with **an additional condition that would take into account this situation if it takes place and remark \ rewrite it into '9999' value for all nulls in the `SequenceNum` field.**

[UPD!] And rewrite "1" value in the very first SequenceNum record as "9999" also.

**Present code** (here it counts an example with inner `SequenceNum` sequences' presence)

```
<Parcel ID="1">
    <EntitySpatial>
        <SpatialElement>

            <SpelementUnit PointNum="1">
                <Ordinate X="100.1" Y="-100.1"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="2">
                <Ordinate X="100.2" Y="-100.2"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="3">
                <Ordinate X="100.3" Y="-100.3"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="4">
                <Ordinate X="100.1" Y="-100.1"/>
            </SpelementUnit>

            <SpelementUnit PointNum="5">
                <Ordinate X="100.5" Y="-100.5"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="6">
                <Ordinate X="100.6" Y="-100.6"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="7">
                <Ordinate X="100.5" Y="-100.5"/>
            </SpelementUnit>

            <SpelementUnit PointNum="8">
                <Ordinate X="100.8" Y="-100.8"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="9">
                <Ordinate X="100.9" Y="-100.9"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="10">
                <Ordinate X="100.11" Y="-100.11"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="1">
                <Ordinate X="100.1" Y="-100.1"/>
            </SpelementUnit>

        </SpatialElement>
    </EntitySpatial>
</Parcel>
<Parcel ID="2">
    <EntitySpatial>
        <SpatialElement>

            <SpelementUnit PointNum="1">
                <Ordinate X="200.1" Y="-200.1"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="2">
                <Ordinate X="200.2" Y="-200.2"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="3">
                <Ordinate X="200.1"" Y="-200.1"/>
            </SpelementUnit>

            <SpelementUnit PointNum="4">
                <Ordinate X="200.4" Y="-200.4"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="5">
                <Ordinate X="200.5" Y="-200.5"/>
            </SpelementUnit>
            <SpelementUnit PointNum="1">
                <Ordinate X="200.1" Y="-200.1"/>
            </SpelementUnit>

        </SpatialElement>
    </EntitySpatial>
</Parcel>
```

'

```
WITH parseXml AS (
SELECT
    base.value('@ID', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Parcel_ID,
    outr.value('for $se in . return count(//SpatialElement[. << $se]) + 1', 'INTEGER') AS SpatialElement_Count,
    outr2.value('for $o in . return count(../SpelementUnit[. << $o]) + 1', 'INTEGER') AS Ordinate_position,
    outr2.value('@PointNum', 'INTEGER') AS PointNum,
    outr2.value('(Ordinate/@X)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Ordinate_X,
    outr2.value('(Ordinate/@Y)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Ordinate_Y
FROM @xml.nodes('Parcels/Parcel') as x(base)
    OUTER APPLY base.nodes('EntitySpatial/SpatialElement') AS B(outr)
    OUTER APPLY outr.nodes('SpelementUnit') AS C(outr2)
),
groups AS (
    SELECT
        Parcel_ID, Ordinate_X, Ordinate_Y,
        --Exclude last row in parcel_id
        MIN(CASE WHEN PointNum = Ordinate_position THEN Ordinate_position END) AS StartSequence,
        MAX(CASE WHEN PointNum = Ordinate_position THEN Ordinate_position END) AS EndSequence,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Parcel_ID
            ORDER BY MIN(CASE WHEN PointNum = Ordinate_position THEN Ordinate_position END)) AS SequenceNum
    FROM
        parseXml
    GROUP BY
        Parcel_ID, Ordinate_X, Ordinate_Y
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT
    ref.Parcel_ID, ref.SpatialElement_Count, ref.Ordinate_X, ref.Ordinate_Y, ref.PointNum,
    groups.SequenceNum
FROM
    parseXml ref
    LEFT JOIN groups
        ON groups.StartSequence <= ref.Ordinate_position
        AND groups.EndSequence >= ref.Ordinate_position
        AND groups.Parcel_ID = ref.Parcel_ID
ORDER BY
    ref.Parcel_ID, Ordinate_position;
```

**the result of this code**

```
+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------+--------------------------+
| Parcel_ID | SpatialElement_Count | Ordinate_X | Ordinate_Y |  PointNum |  SequenceNum |
+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------+--------------------------+
|         1 |                    1 |      100.1 |     -100.1 |         1 |        1     |
|         1 |                    1 |      100.2 |     -100.2 |         2 |        1     |
|         1 |                    1 |      100.3 |     -100.3 |         3 |        1     |
|         1 |                    1 |      100.1 |     -100.1 |         4 |        1     |
|           |                      |            |            |           |              | 
|         1 |                    1 |      100.5 |     -100.5 |         5 |        2     |
|         1 |                    1 |      100.6 |     -100.6 |         6 |        2     |
|         1 |                    1 |      100.5 |     -100.5 |         7 |        2     |
|           |                      |            |            |           |              |  
|         1 |                    1 |      100.8 |     -100.8 |         8 |      null    |
|         1 |                    1 |      100.9 |     -100.9 |         9 |      null    |
|         1 |                    1 |     100.11 |    -100.11 |        10 |      null    |
|         1 |                    1 |      100.1 |     -100.1 |         1 |      null    |
|           |                      |            |            |           |              |  
|           |                      |            |            |           |              |  
|         2 |                    2 |      200.1 |     -200.1 |         1 |       3      |
|         2 |                    2 |      200.2 |     -200.2 |         2 |       3      |
|         2 |                    2 |      200.1 |     -200.1 |         3 |       3      |
|           |                      |            |            |           |              |  
|         2 |                    2 |      200.4 |     -200.4 |         4 |      null    |
|         2 |                    2 |      200.5 |     -200.5 |         5 |      null    |
|         2 |                    2 |      200.1 |     -200.1 |         1 |      null    |
+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------+--------------------------+
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

"9999" value in `SequenceNum` column for all points if there is no inner sequence chains

Comment: so if SequenceNum is NULL in the final result you want it replaced with 9999?  If that's the case then replace `groups.SequenceNum` with `COALESCE(groups.SequenceNum, 9999) AS SequenceNum`

Comment: @TimMylott 
Thank you for this hint... But the question is a little more complicated. I will clarify.
Your option is a kind of global condition that replaces all nulls with 9999. Whereas I need all the numbers to be replaced only when the described case occurs (no additional internal sequences). It also means that in this case a) That the first "1" value record in the `SequenceNum` (which is also `PointNum`=1) should also be replaced with 9999 (besides nulls). b) if the internal chains are formed (like in the sample code) - nulls must be saved (do not replaced).